# how to generate html from cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, roslyn

I need to validate if html has more then single h1 tag.
My project is mvc cshml razor files which requrires models.

How to generate full html from cshtml and mockup models ?
It that possible with Rosylyn ?

I tried this way but i still can't render paritals inside
what I want to achive it end html with all partials in cshtml rendered

```
var ws = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();

            // Store the translation keys...

            string solutionRoot = @"C:\src\";
            string sln = solutionRoot + "website.sln";

            // Load the solution, and find all the cshtml Razor views...
            var solution =  ws.OpenSolutionAsync(sln).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            var projects = solution.Projects;
            var mainProj = solution.Projects.Where(x => x.Name == "Portal").Single();
            FileInfo[] cshtmls = new DirectoryInfo(solutionRoot).GetFiles("*.cshtml", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            //// Go through each Razor View - generate the equivalent CS and add to the project for compilation.
            var host = new RazorEngineHost(RazorCodeLanguage.Languages["cshtml"]);
            var razor = new RazorTemplateEngine(host);
            var cs = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            var csOptions = new CodeGeneratorOptions();
            foreach (var cshtml in cshtmls.Where(x=>x.Name.Contains("Index")))
            {
                using (StreamReader re = new StreamReader(cshtml.FullName))
                {

                        // Let Razor do it's thang...
                        var compileUnit = razor.GenerateCode(re).GeneratedCode;

                        // Pull the code into a stringbuilder, and append to the main project:
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        using (StringWriter rw = new StringWriter(sb))
                        {
                            cs.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(compileUnit, rw, csOptions);
                        }

                        var content = sb.ToString();
                }
            }
```

Comment: How are you going to handle conditional logic that is based on the model content? This is going to affect the output and therefore the validity of your result.

Comment: just created some static model, and be able to pass to rosylyn to compile cshtml into html , this is what i want to achive

Comment: To rephrase: if the value of a given model property influences the generated HTML (e.g. adding more HTML to the page); would this not impact the validity of your finding whether or not there is only one `<h1>` tag on the page? If so, how are you expecting to test all possible values of the model's properties? What about properties that are collections of complex objects? etc

Comment: this is not matter at this point, what i want to achive is the mechanizm to be able to render it

Comment: did you ever get this sorted? I'm looking for a similar approach. I need to pass a model to razor and get the html which I think is what you were after.